# Abutted rect elements in SVG leave a tiny gap

Tags: svg

I am trying to create a color palette using SVG. For this, I about many `rect` elements and just change the style for each one.
The issue is that, sometimes, there is tiny sliver of white between the elements, as in this image:

[image: svg palette]

This snapshot was taken in Chrome on OSX. Safari looks similar.

In my code `viewBox` is not constant and can vary depending on the number of rectangles. Additionally, width and height can also vary depending on chosen resolution. In other words, I can't play with these to make this one look right.

I tried creating each rect a bit wider than necessary, but the effect was the same. In teh above picture the top row has a width of `100.1`, while the bottom has `100`. Making the width `101` worked, but I can't use this since in some cases the expected width of a `rect` could be single digits, so an extra 1 to the width is significant overlap.

I tried adding a stroke, but that didn't work as the required width to make this work depends on `viewBox` and `rect` sizes.

Have you seen this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000">
        <g>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
            <rect x="100" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,250)"></rect>
            <rect x="200" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,245)"></rect>
            <rect x="300" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,240)"></rect>
            <rect x="400" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,235)"></rect>
            <rect x="500" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,230)"></rect>
            <rect x="600" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,225)"></rect>
            <rect x="700" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,220)"></rect>
            <rect x="800" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,215)"></rect>
            <rect x="900" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,210)"></rect>
            <rect x="1000" y="0" width="100.1", height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,205)"></rect>
            <rect x="1100" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,200)"></rect>
            <rect x="1200" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,195)"></rect>
            <rect x="1300" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,190)"></rect>
            <rect x="1400" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,185)"></rect>
            <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
            <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,10,250)"></rect>
            <rect x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,20,245)"></rect>
            <rect x="300" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,30,240)"></rect>
            <rect x="400" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,40,235)"></rect>
            <rect x="500" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,50,230)"></rect>
            <rect x="600" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,60,225)"></rect>
            <rect x="700" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,70,220)"></rect>
            <rect x="800" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,80,215)"></rect>
            <rect x="900" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,90,210)"></rect>
            <rect x="1000" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,100,205)"></rect>
            <rect x="1100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,110,200)"></rect>

            <rect x="1200" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,120,195)"></rect>
            <rect x="1300" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,130,190)"></rect>
            <rect x="1400" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,140,185)"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's antialiasing, try set shape-rendering="crispEdges" as an attribute on the `<g>` parent element to disable that.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000">
        <g shape-rendering="crispEdges">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
            <rect x="100" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,250)"></rect>
            <rect x="200" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,245)"></rect>
            <rect x="300" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,240)"></rect>
            <rect x="400" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,235)"></rect>
            <rect x="500" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,230)"></rect>
            <rect x="600" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,225)"></rect>
            <rect x="700" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,220)"></rect>
            <rect x="800" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,215)"></rect>
            <rect x="900" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,210)"></rect>
            <rect x="1000" y="0" width="100.1", height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,205)"></rect>
            <rect x="1100" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,200)"></rect>
            <rect x="1200" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,195)"></rect>
            <rect x="1300" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,190)"></rect>
            <rect x="1400" y="0" width="100.1" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,185)"></rect>
            <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)"></rect>
            <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,10,250)"></rect>
            <rect x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,20,245)"></rect>
            <rect x="300" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,30,240)"></rect>
            <rect x="400" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,40,235)"></rect>
            <rect x="500" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,50,230)"></rect>
            <rect x="600" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,60,225)"></rect>
            <rect x="700" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,70,220)"></rect>
            <rect x="800" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,80,215)"></rect>
            <rect x="900" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,90,210)"></rect>
            <rect x="1000" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,100,205)"></rect>
            <rect x="1100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,110,200)"></rect>

            <rect x="1200" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,120,195)"></rect>
            <rect x="1300" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,130,190)"></rect>
            <rect x="1400" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,140,185)"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```